# How to close a google chrome "newest" tab via terminal(equivalent to Ctrl+W command)

Tags: shortcut-keys

My W key just broke so i'm trying to be creative and make a shortcut for closing the newest tab in chrome.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: just go to settings, and change the shortcut (**Ctrl** + **Y** for example)

Comment: You can also use a chrome extension that customize its shortcuts like for example : Shortkeys (Custom Keyboard Shortcuts)

Comment: Is it broken only for Chrome? What are you going to do when you want to just type `w`???